# Setting of the DEBUG level for development in the play framework

Tags: debugging, logging, playframework

Is there something specific which can prevent debug messages from appearing in the console?
Or what settings should make sure they do appear?

I had debug messages showing for the last two days, but they don't appear anymore for some reason, and I am at a loss what changed. I added some information for the test and development i'ids' but nothing to do with the logging level.

Any hints would be really appreciated!

current values:

```
application.mode=dev
application.log=DEBUG
application.log.path=/log4j.dev.properties
```

in log4j.dev.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Console
log4j.logger.play=INFO
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache=WARN
log4j.logger.bytecodeparser=ERROR

# Console
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p ~ %m%n
```

Comment: By any chance, don't you launch your Play app in PROD mode ?

Comment: No, but it seems a bug, a friend pointed out. The line application.log.path=/log4j.dev.properties in application.conf caused it, and commenting it out solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems a bug in the play framework. The line application.log.path=/log4j.dev.properties in application.conf caused it, and commenting it out solved it.